# string formatting with lists doesn't work in python

Tags: python, list, range

I wanted to use string formatting instead of this messy way

```
data=(1, 8)
a=((list(range((data[0]), ((data[-1])+1)))))
print (a)
```

but when I tried to use string formatting I had a syntax error

```
data=(1, 8)
a=((list(range(%f,%f))) % data)
print(a)
```

I tried %s instead of %f

```
data=(1, 8)
a=((list(range(%s,%s))) % data)
print(a)
```

Comment: `%f` and `%s` have to be used inside format strings, it makes no sense to put them in the arguments to `range()`.

Comment: What is your expected output/format?

Comment: I think what you're really looking for is `range(*data)`

Comment: ... you aren't formatting  string, so why do you think string formatting would work?

Comment: You seem to have parentheses around every single subexpression except the integer literals. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Barmar `range(*data)` is nice but does not include `data[-1]`.

Comment: @DyZ Neither does his attempts that try to use the formatting operator, so I assumed that wasn't important.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but the first example includes the range end.

Answer (score 0):

`range(data[0], data[-1] + 1)` is the best you can get. The value of this expression is a range, not a list. If you plan to use it further in a loop, list comprehension, etc., just leave it the way it is. If you really need a list (probably you do not), convert the range to a list: `list(range(data[0], data[-1] + 1))`.

You other option is `list(range(*data)) + [data[-1]]`, but it is even worse-looking.

Answer (score 0):

In this exact cast, you can actually just call `list(data)` and get what you want. Also, you're overusing you're parenthesis. The first statement could be reduced to this:

```
a = list(range(data[0], data[-1]+1)
```

Or, technically, just this:

```
a = list(data)
```

Now, if you actually want to generate a range between two values stored in a tuple, you can also use

```
a = range(*data)
```

The `*` prefix unpacks the data in an iterable. You can actually store arguments this way. For instance:

```
args = (6, 2)
pow(*args)
```

Is identical to

```
args = (6, 2)
pow(args[0], args[1])
```

So, in you're exact case, `a = range(*data)` will generate `a = range(1, 8)`. Not what exactly what you wanted, but may be useful.